# How to pass click event into setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event and in that click event I need to use a setTimeOut function, reason is because when I try to show an overlay, it doesn't happen, but when I put it into a function then the remaining functions into a timeout then it works. Its the only solution I can find but the problem is is that the setTimeOut isn't recognizing the click event..If this isn't making much sense, then hopefully the code will speak for itself

```
function TurnItOn() {
    $('#SiteOverlayFullScreen').css('display', 'block');
}

$(document).on('click', '#ddValidation ul li', function (e) {
        TurnItOn();
        let self = e;
        setTimeout(function () {
            let selectedItem = e.target.text;
            let rightPanelWidth = $('#innerVertical').width();

            $('#ddValidation ul li').removeClass('active-font-size');

            //$('#SiteOverlayFullScreen').css('display', 'block');
            //StartBusyIndicator('#SiteOverlayFullScreen');

            switch (selectedItem) {
                case 'Quote': {
                    //StartBusyIndicator('#SiteOverlayFullScreen');

                    e.currentTarget.classList.add('active-font-size');

                    $('#innerVertical').addClass('show-validation-window');

                    $('#ValidationWindow').css({ 'display': 'block', width: rightPanelWidth });

                    $('#btnSplitScreen').trigger('click');

                    CheckValidationResultsByRoomsInQuote();

                    //$('#SiteOverlayFullScreen').css('display', 'none');

                } break;
                case 'Room': {
                    e.currentTarget.classList.add('active-font-size');

                    $('#innerVertical').addClass('show-validation-window');

                    $('#ValidationWindow').css({ 'display': 'block', width: rightPanelWidth });

                    $('#btnSplitScreen').trigger('click');

                    CheckValidationResultsByRoomInQuote();

                    //$('#SiteOverlayFullScreen').css('display', 'none');

                } break;
                default: {
                    e.currentTarget.classList.add('active-font-size');
                    $('#ValidationWindow').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#innerVertical').removeClass('show-validation-window');
                    $('#btnSplitScreen').trigger('click');

                    ResetValidationErrorLabels();

                    //$('#SiteOverlayFullScreen').css('display', 'none');
                } break;
            }
        });
});
```

The error that gets thrown, in any of the case statements, is

> Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: `$(e.currentTarget).addClass('active-font-size')` might be a useful place to start. Doesn't answer the question or guarantee validity: however, not really a point mixing not-JQ and JQ here.

Comment: Just gave that a shot and even just tried $(e) but the current target at that point is the document

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the switch statement, not so much the setTimeOut

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't need to pass the event to the function, because it has a closure on it. The inner function can definitely access `e`. What is inside it is another matter.

Comment: @Aioros, yes in the setTimeOut I can still access the 'e', but as I previously mentioned, that it isn't accessible in the switch

Comment: Can we see the relevant HTML?

Comment: I found a way to access the 'e' in the switch statement, and its an ugly and as best as I can tell, bad programming practice, but I put into the e into a global variable...Or I could have just given the list elements id's and did it that way

Comment: Nope, placing it into a global variable didn't work either. currentTarget is document. Looks like the way to go is the list elements with IDs

Comment: So your problem is that currentTarget is the document instead of the element. setTimeout has nothing to do with it. You need to figure out why the event is being captured by the document.

Answer (score -1):

try use $(this) instead of e.currentTarget and then addClass eg. `$(this).addClass('my-class')`

Comment: Won't work. Since he is in the setTimeout function, *this* is rebound to the window.

Comment: are you try maybe `let that = this;` out of setTimeout function and in timeout function use that

Comment: You need to direct the correct answer to the OP, not me.